# check if list contains a item with title or not

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have a asp.net bulleted list, I want to check if any item in bulleted list has title equal to something, if not then tell me.

This is what I am trying but not giving me yes or no,

```
$("[id$=bulletedListFruits]").children().getByTitle('mango')
```

Comment: mango is name of fruit

Comment: What do you mean by 'title'? Title attribute or what???

Comment: @A.Wolff please hold on for a second, drink a cold glass of water and read my question again please :-)

Comment: So you want to check if any children inside "[id$=bulletedListFruits]" has a title attribute equal to `mango`??? What is `getByTitle()` method? EDIT: i just realize i don't know what you are talking about (asp.net bulleted list), so please forget my comments

Comment: @A.Wolff, yes that's right, I tried using getByTitle but it gives error

Answer (score 0):

you could use the `:contains()` function.

```
$("[id$=bulletedListFruits]").find(':contains("mango")')
```

the definition is [here](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/)

Comment: @CustomizedName how can we know what is supposed to be `mango`. Reread your own question please...

Comment: From your defninition mango appears to be a variable. I have updated the answer with a generic implementation

Comment: @CustomizedName "ReferenceError: mango is not defined" No it is not or you comment doesn't make any sense at all... EDIT: ok, we can see it now...

Answer (score 0):

As i see it, you want something like that:

```
var $elemWithTitleMango = $("[id$=bulletedListFruits]").children('[title="mango"]');
```

To return true or false, false if no element has title equal to mango, use:

```
var isThereAnyElementWithTitleMango = !!$("[id$=bulletedListFruits]").children('[title="mango"]').length;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I wanted,

```
var longlong = false;

$("[id$=bulletedListFruits] li").each(function (index) {
                    if ($(this).text() == "mango")
                        longlong = true;
                });

if(longlong)   // perform some logic here
```

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what you are expecting here with returning true or false from each anonymous function. Don't you want to use `.filter()` instead? FYI, text as nothing to do with title ;)

Comment: I tried both above answers, but non worked for me :(, except above

Comment: But here your return statements doesn't affect currently matched set

Comment: Plus you have "Mango" in your answer but "mango" in your question. this will affect the output as JS is case-sensitive. so both of us (myself and a. wolff) would not have returned correctly for you.

Comment: @Qpirate thanks for being clever, but I added above as example, it's not real code, if your answer would had worked, I would had accepted them :)